# html hyperlinks not working correctly for some devices

Tags: html, css

I have two hyperlinks in two paragraphs. They both work on my phone, only the second works on my laptop, and none work on my iPad.

```
<div class="about-me">
  <p>Kevin (Quito [Key'-tow]) Williams is an aspiring front-end web designer.
     He has 5 years of experience in HTML, 4 years experience in CSS, and is
     currently studying jQuery. As a modern web designer, he is using his
     coding background to study the latest web technologies: HTML5, CSS3, <a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design">RWD</a>.
     In addition to his web technology languages, he also has experience in:
     C<sup>++</sup>, Javascript, Java, Perl, Lua (Minecraft based), LISP, SQL.
  </p>
  <p>During his 5<sup><sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub></sup> years of <a target="_blank" href="http://www.wau.edu">college</a>, he took many computer
     science classes in his pursuit of his current Bachelor of Science
     Degree in Mathematics. Near the end of his studies, he took an
     interest in Web Development, and decided to pursue it as a career.
     He is trying to start his career as a freelancer, at least until he
     lands the job he wants.
  </p>
</div><!-- /about-me -->


.about-me a {
  font-size: 2em;
  background: #ff9500; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #ff9500); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #ff9500); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #ff9500); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(white, #ff9500); /* Standard syntax */
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  padding: 10px;
}

.about-me a {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The anchor CSS is split because the second one has the same CSS as some other elements.

I have the `ontouchstart` attribute for the body in my HTML. Any idea of why this is so? I have CSS that affects the links, but it is only aesthetics; nothing that would stop anything from happening.

Comment: I am not sure, but did you look up the Browser Support for Anchor Tag?
like for CSS they have --webkit etc.
It may be different for Safari, Chrome etc. as CSS is differently supported and so are some of the tags as well (totally based on my memory from 4 years ago. So, can't say for sure)

Comment: In general without CSS if I run the sample code with both anchor tags then they work.
So, I believe that it has to do with CSS to some extent.
Look up webkit and CSS Browser Support and Anchor Tag support as I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: anchor tags are supported in all major browsers, from what I read from w3schools tutorial.

Comment: I took off the CSS and it's the same thing.

Comment: Oh I was mentioning about their associated CSS.
Probably if it is possible for you to put some more code snippet then it will be better.
Someone else can also look that up.
Or if you can also provide us the Inspect element summary.
You should also use Chrome and check the tag with Inspect element that what exactly is happening to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Javascript code which might be causing the issue? It's very strange that `<a></a>` tags aren't working, they're pretty standard across all browsers.